# EXT-JS ui not updating after adding data to store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

i am trying to add item to combo-box after its created but in store data get added but its not updated in UI.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: ["name", "value"],


        listeners: {
            load: function(store, rec) {
                store.add([["val1",1],["val2",2]]);
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        valueField: "value",
        displayField: "name",
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    var s2 = Ext.getStore('simpsonsStore');
    s2.loadData([["val3",3]],true);
});
```

Val1 and Val2 are added first. after render i want to add val3

Comment: code on jsfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/kqpq25hL/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `autoload=true` assumes there's no data and is whipping `s2.loadData()` which gets executed first.
This doesn't happen in latest versions.

Manually calling `store.load()` with no autoload solves the problem. Also combobox needs to queryMode='local'

Similar working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tonymayoral/8jzfo7zj/1/

```
var st=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        //autoLoad: true,
        fields: ["name", "value"],

        listeners: {
            load: function(store, rec) {
                store.add([["val1",1],["val2",2]]);
            }
        }
    });

    st.load(); 

    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        valueField: "value",
        displayField: "name",
        queryMode:'local', //needs to be local
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    var s2 = Ext.getStore('simpsonsStore');
    s2.loadData([["val3",3]],true)
```